# Finding Euclidean Distance on String features

Tags: java, machine-learning, classification

I am trying to implement K-Nearest Neighbors algorithm. My dataset has values like:

```
164     5.60    3.17    30.98   Present 44  25.99   43.20   53  1

178     0.95    4.75    21.06   Absent  49  23.74   24.69   61  0
```

I am planning to use Euclidian Distance to calculate the distance between the two vectors. I have question as to how to compute the ED between two Strings for e.g. "Present" and "Absent" in the above example?

Comment: I am trying to map it to numerical values as suggested below in the comments. Yet to complete it. Will update once I am done!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should identify the possible values list, depending on the specific **problem's domain**, for example "Absent", "Present", "Unknown" etc. Then you should map a numerical value to each string value, corresponding to the **problem's domain**. You should take the **distance** of the mapped numerical values into account. For example, I would consider "Absent" and "Present" more **distant** than the "Absent" and "Unknown". Therefore, I would map the values like "Absent":1, "Unknown":0, "Present":-1. This depends heavily on the domain of the specific problem.

Then you would calculate the euclidean distance using the numerical values.

Hope I helped!

Comment: yes, I do agree - this is a good approach. You can calculate difference between strings as well, but it will be how many changes are needed to transform first string into the second (Levenstheim distance), not distance in meaning. Therefore change to numbers should help.

Comment: You are right. The method you describe calculates a distance between two strings. But the distance that you are referring to, **does not have the semantics that my distance has**. You mean the lexical distance (if the term is right) which actually expresses how difficult is to convert the first string to the second by letter transformation. The distance I propose would be arbitrarily defined according to the semantics of the whole word and the problem's domain. Just to clarify...